# Is there a way to dynamically import SCSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, sass

I have a modal overlay and i only need the js/template/scss when the user takes action to open the overlay, I have dynamically imported the JS and the template. using async await. But is there a way to dynamically import specified stylesheets?

I have tried

```
var styles = document.createElement('link');
    styles.type="text/css";
    styles.rel="stylesheet";
    styles.href='../scss/Overlay.scss';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styles);
```

The styles are being applied this way but, i keep getting this error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Comment: Browsers don't read SCSS files directly anyway. Only CSS.

Comment: Right, SCSS gets compiled down into CSS right? So its not possible to load a SCSS file dynamically?

Comment: Oh yes, it is very possible. I think what you did is a good attempt. If the route "path/to/Overlay.css" is valid, if your server serves it, then it should work. Currently, it just seems to be a wrong path. You just have to require the right file to your server (I don't know which server you use, so I can't tell you how though)